# Trying to conditionally insert a newline in my ZSH prompt. Having trouble figuring it out

Tags: shell, zsh

I have the following in my .zshrc:

```
PROMPT=$'$(ps1_head)[%F{32}%n@%m%f %~]%(!.#.$) '

function ps1_head ()
{
  var=${vcs_info_msg_0_}
  [ ! -z "$var" ] && printf '%b\n' $var
}
```

It works in that I get my git prompt.   But the newline is never inserted.   How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a command substitution like `$(...)`, trailing newlines are trimmed from the
replacement text, so the `\n` isn't included in the resulting prompt string.

Note that it's only the last newlines that are removed; newlines in the middle
are retained.  So a simple fix would be to add some text (e.g. a space) after
the newline:

```
autoload -Uz vcs_info
setopt PROMPT_SUBST

PROMPT=$'$(ps1_head)[%F{32}%n@%m%f %~]%(!.#.$) '

function ps1_head() {
  vcs_info
  var=${vcs_info_msg_0_}
  [ -n "$var" ] && printf '%s\n ' "$var"
}
```

For more formatting flexibility, it's often easier to use a zsh `precmd`:

```
my_precmd() {
  vcs_info
  [[ -n $vcs_info_msg_0_ ]] && print $vcs_info_msg_0_
}

autoload -Uz vcs_info
zstyle ':vcs_info:git:*' formats '(%s)-[%b]'
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook precmd my_precmd
PROMPT='[%F{32}%n@%m%f %~]%(!.#.$) '
```

The precmd will be executed prior to every prompt being displayed, and can print
information and set variables. It's frequently used to fill in the `psvar` array, which
is easy to use in a zsh prompt. The `zstyle` command can be used to format the
output from `vcs_info`.